# Glitch between cells in IE/Edge when using border-radius

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

In IE 10+ and Edge the `background` of the `table` leaks through the bottom of the cells when `border-radius` is applied. Any ideas for fix or workaround?

I've set up an example here, with red `background` on the table-element:

```css
table {
  background: red;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>In IE 10+ and Edge: the red background of the table leaks through the bottom of the cells when border-radius is applied</p>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/phobia/pen/ezmXvb)

---

Example of rendering in most browsers:

[image: Example of rendering in most browsers]

Example of rendering in IE10+/Edge:

[image: Example of rendering in IE10+/Edge]

Comment: It might be a solution to add divs inside the columns and add a border-radius and background on those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `line-height:1` in `td`, with this the height goes from `18.4px` to `16px` given the `font-size` by default is `16px`

### UPDATE

(OP's Comment)

> Thank you for the reply, and I suppose this is a solution. The
>   weakness that my simplified example doesn't show, is that if the table
>   width is set to 100%, at certain window-width I have the same issue
>   with vertical lines. You wouldn't happen to have a trick up your
>   sleave for that issue as well?

you can solve that issue by adding a `border-right` to `td` with the same color as `background` of `td`

```css
table {
  background: red;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
  /* for easier display */
  padding: 1em; 
  /* fix horizontal line */
  line-height: 1; 
}
 /* fix vertical-line that sometimes shows up */
tr td:first-of-type {
 border-right:1px solid white
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>In IE 10+ and Edge: the red background of the table leaks through the bottom of the cells when border-radius is applied</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and I suppose this is a solution. The weakness that my simplified example doesn't show, is that if the table width is set to 100%, at certain window-width I have the same issue with vertical lines.

You wouldn't happen to have a trick up your sleave for that issue as well? :)

Comment: I'm on my lunch break now as soon as possible I will see that.